# Django: User information split between "User" and "Person" models

Tags: python, django

Whenever I create a new account, the information I enter "first_name", "last_name", "username", "age", "city", "state", "email" gets split between the built-in User model and the Person model I created. I can see this happening on the admin site, when I click on a user I just created.

Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

View for creating an account:

```
def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"],
                    email=request.POST["email"],
                    first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                    last_name=request.POST["last_name"])
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        Person.objects.create(user=new_user,
                          age=str(request.POST.get("age")),
                          city=str(request.POST.get("city")),
                          state=str(request.POST.get("state")))
        new_user.is_active = True
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

I know the problem is in this model and view, I just can't conceptualize how to put all of the information I submit into the Person model (since the User model only has "first_name", "last_name", "email" attributes).

Comment: Not answering your questions (@wim is right) but just providing some tips. You shouldn't have to use `request.POST.get`. Using the `ModelForm` is a lot more practical (handles validation and less code). You can post 2 forms with prefixes or group these under 1 big form. Also, if you are just starting this project, you might consider replacing the `User` model instead of adding a `Person` model.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've seen a lot of people using ModelForm for validation and the like, and I was thinking about tinkering with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Person` model has a one-to-one with the `User`, you don't need to store `username`, `first_name`, and `last_name` fields on it.  Just leave them on the `User` model and access them through the relation, you are after all using a *relational database*.

Comment: Wonderful! I just tried that and it worked like a charm.